# Двоичный поиск в кортеже

Tags: python

Как реализовать двоичный поиск ключа в кортеже.

```
dictionary= {
int(input("Введите 1-й ключ: ")):"Царицын",   
int(input("Введите 2-й ключ: ")):"Петроград",
int(input("Введите 3-й ключ: ")):"Вятка",
int(input("Введите 4-й ключ: ")):"Екатеринодар",
int(input("Введите 5-й ключ: ")):"Ново-Николаевск",
}
print("Словарь:", dictionary)
sorted_tuple = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
print("Отсортированный по возрастанию словарь: ", sorted_tuple)

x= int(input("Введите ключ который нужно найти "))
m=-1
count=0
```

Насколько я понимаю нужно использовать цикл for, но как он должен выглядеть при поиске по кортежу?

Comment: Забыл указать. Переменная m нужна для случая если ключ не найден (в цикле просто планирую ей присваивать значение), а count - счетчик.

Comment: а зачем вам бинарный поиск, если в словаре у вас будет поиск за константное время: `if x in dictionary`

Comment: @Zhihar По заданию должен реализовать алгоритм бинарного поиска)

Comment: тогда вам сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212358/binary-search-bisection-in-python